# How to integrate a ZeroMQ socket into a glib main loop?

Tags: c, linux, glib, zeromq

I wanted to add a ZeroMQ socket to a glib program.

The pitty is, a zmq socket is not `poll()`-able, and they give their implementation, which overloads the old `poll()` func. How could I integrate that into the main loop efficiently? I tried using their poll ( `zmq_poll()` ) instead of the default one, but there's no good way of giving it the zmq socket, besides from making it a `global`.

Defining a new `GSource` works, but it can get high CPU usage ( by setting `timeout = 0` ) or arbitrary poll timeouts ( e.g. setting `timeout = 100` to be polled at least every 100 ms ), which is not really efficient, since there is the possibility of polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that newer zmq libraries support the **`ZMQ_FD`** `getsockopt()` parameter, which gives you back a unix **`fd`** which you can `poll()`. The only caveat is that you can't just `poll()` it to know if you can `recv()` or `send()` from / to it, but you need to use the **`ZMQ_EVENTS`** `getsockopt()` parameter to get back the real `fd` status.

It seems to be working quite well in glib.

Comment: because sockets are used by zmq in not obvious ways, so a simple poll is just telling you there's activity on the socket, but to know the real zmq socket state you need another layer of indirection

Comment: Looks like you’ve found the two appropriate answers here: either using `ZMQ_FD`, or writing a custom `GSource`. A custom `GSource` should not necessarily need to decide between high CPU usage and arbitrary timeouts: it sounds like the `prepare()` or `check()` implementations in your custom `GSource` are returning `TRUE` spuriously.

Answer (score 1):

According to [FAQ](http://www.zeromq.org/area:faq) you could try "the other way" approach. Rather than making `poll` on a *zmq socket* try `zmq_poll()` on a regular *socket*.

Check out question **How can I integrate ØMQ sockets with normal sockets? Or with a GUI event loop?** in the FAQ.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the FAQ. That's an option, as I said in my question, but it's annoying that glib want a poll() function pointer, to which they just give a set of fds. Adding the zmq sockets must be done sideloading them, by making them global.